# jQuery click event on insertBefore method

Tags: javascript, jquery

While working on some plugin, I saw this kind of jQuery code:

```
$("element").insertBefore(closest_elem.closest('li')).find('.ex-class').click();
```

I am interested in what click event is doing here?

Also I want to add class to this element after it is inserted in document, and I wonder how can I do it.

Comment: That .click() is just triggering the **click** event on the element (s) found, if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Looks like two independent questions. I'd ask the second one as separate question and provided more details about it.

Comment: `Also I want to add class to this element after it is inserted in document` Why **after**? Anyway, then just use `addClass('myClass')` after `insertBefore()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a trigger. When you use `$("selector").Click()` without any parameter, all of the selector that selected with `$("selector")`, will be clicked and click event of them will be fired.

May be you can find an event handler like this in that code too:

```
$('.ex-class').on('click', function(){....})
```